# Как лучше организовать адреса на сайте?

Tags: seo, чпу

Сайт вопросов и ответов. На сайте в данный момент имеется 2 тыс. вопросов, расположенных в 27 категориях (авто, игры, софт и т.д.), как лучше организовать адреса к вопросам, есть два варианта:

Первый вариант:

1. site.ru/auto/23489
2. site.ru/games/57659
3. site.ru/health_beauty/85989

Второй вариант (q от слова question):

1. site.ru/q/23489
2. site.ru/q/57659
3. site.ru/q/85989

Преимущества первого варианта в ранжировании поисковиками, в ссылках содержатся главные ключевые слова (auto, games, health_beauty и т.д.) которые поисковики очень любят, также они будут лучше понимать структура сайта и отображать её в сниппете, недостаток варианта в том, что если вопрос будет перемещен из одной категории в другую необходимо настраивать переадресацию, а если будет переименована категория, то переадресацию для всех вопросов категории. Второй вариант наоборот хуже в плане продвижения, но меньше проблем в организации. Что выбрать?

Comment: В первом варианте переадресация реализуется ровно один раз для всех товаров сразу, поэтому этой проблемы просто не существует. А поисковики будут читать структуру сайта из микроразметки, которую вам желательно потрудиться написать, тогда им будет совершенно плевать на структуру в ссылках

Comment: Микроразметка присутствует, я про другую структуру, которая отображается в спиппете поисовика, в первом варианте она будет намного красивее "gdeska.ru > Авто, Транспорт >  Где купить Ладу Гранту?", во втором варианте просто gdeska.ru > q/85989

Comment: Я тоже про неё, именно она прекрасно задаётся с помощью микроразметки, а не ссылок ([в справке Google есть подробности](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb)) (по крайней мере я там не вижу каких-либо требований к формату ссылок)

Comment: А в Яндексе тоже?

Comment: Про яндекс не в курсе, хотя в интернете пишут, что микроразметку он не учитывает и строит всё сам как попало по непредсказуемым алгоритмам. Если для вас это очень важно и вы очень беспокоитесь за хлебные крошки в Яндексе — ну, используйте первый вариант, что ли)

Comment: Спасибо большое, обязательно прочту про микроразметку.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант все же лучше, как минимум тем что понятно сразу куда она ведёт. Во втором же нужно будет переходить по ссылке а затем смотреть что там, не многие доверяют таким урезанным ссылкам.

Comment: спасибо за совет, учту

Answer (score 1):

Согласно Справке Гугл **[Руководство по поисковой оптимизации для начинающих](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=ru)** => **Простые URL более информативны**:

> Описательные категории и имена файлов для документов на вашем сайте не только улучшают его структуру, но и позволяют сделать ссылки на ваш контент понятными для пользователей. Посетителей могут озадачить слишком длинные и непонятные URL.
>
> Пользователи могут разместить ссылку на вашу страницу в виде текста, а слова в URL гораздо информативнее для пользователей, чем **непонятные идентификаторы или параметры**.
>
> Используйте простую структуру каталогов
> Систематизируйте свой контент так, чтобы структура каталогов позволяла пользователям легко ориентироваться на сайте, а URL отражали содержание страниц.
> Чего следует избегать:
> Структур с глубоким вложением подкаталогов, например ".../dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/page.html".

Таким образом я также присоединяюсь к имеющимся рекомендациям о то, что первый вариант более понятен пользователям. Однако создайте такие же "говорящие" названия для веб-страниц этих каталогов. Это не должны быть цифровые идентификаторы, которые вы указали в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый совет, очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

[Структура сайта](https://domhtml.ru/struktura-sajta-seo/) — это не только удобная навигация для будущих клиентов. Это более глобальный инструмент, включающий перспективы развития и продвижения бизнеса в сети. Поэтому формировать структуру следует до создания контента и визуала. Ведь в нее закладывают не только существующие возможности, но и точки для раскрытия потенциала организации в будущем